# how to crawl vue.js based website with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I've tried to crawl a website using beautifulsoup and I've encountered with:

`<p data-v-57d17052 class="text text--gray70 text--subtitle2">Hello</p>`

and this, for some reason, doesn't allow me to use beatifulsoup's features.

`title = soup.find_all(class_={"text, text--gray70, text--subtitle2"})`

I think `data-v-57d17052` is causing this difficulty.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I have tried all beautifulsoup's features and it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from the `class_=`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = ''''<p data-v-57d17052 class="text text--gray70 text--subtitle2">Hello</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(class_={"text text--gray70 text--subtitle2"})
print(title.text)
```

Prints:

```
Hello
```

---

You can use also a CSS selector:

```
title = soup.select_one(".text.text--gray70.text--subtitle2")
print(title.text)
```